# Safari nested flex issue

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, flex-grow

Nested flex box with sibling as **flex-grow : 1** and **overflow-y : auto** doesn't works as expected in Safari [My build 13.1 (14609.1.20.111.8)]. This works great again in Chrome. Attached the screenshots of the both items along with a minimum reproducible code block.

If we give a fixed size to flex-basis : [n]px to the second child.. it works fine. But we cannot always expect to give that as the content inside the second item is dynamic. Here in below code block giving it for show a minimum reproducible use case.

[image]

```css
.parent {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.fixedChild {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.growingChild {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
.fancyButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #0076D1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #0076D1;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="growingChild">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    
  </div>
  <div class="fixedChild">
    <button class="fancyButton" type="button">button 1</button>
    <button class="fancyButton" type="button">button 1</button>
    <button class="fancyButton" type="button">button 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not address the underlying inconsistency, but setting the last child(flex item) to :

```css
flex-shrink: 0;
```

Appears to make Safari and Chrome behave the same where the flex container accounts for the button's height along with the growing flex item sibling. Not sure who is right or wrong there but I feel like maybe Safari ?

Comment: good answer use by code... you can copy codes very easy... please read help center and get tour site for achieved best feedback . https://stackoverflow.com/tour